# How are PCS upgrades obtained?

Tags: xcom-2

So far, I have only ever seen PCS upgrades available as purchases in return for intel on the Black Market. Are there other ways of obtaining them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCSs can either be dropped by killed enemies, akin to weapon attachments (although they do seem to be much rarer than attachments), or they can be purchased on the Black Market for roughly 20-30 intel.

Comment: Ah! Never seen one drop off an enemy. Maybe they get more common later in the game...

Comment: @SimonW Looks like it might be the case, as mine didn't drop until I made "significant" progress through the story.

Comment: There's also a Geoscape scanning event with the reward "Assorted Loot" that can have mods and PCS in it.